# Sending tokens from one Address to Another

Tags: tokens, binance-smart-chain

I am new to this. So please no flaming.
I created a token on binance smart chain and i want to send from one Token address to another token address, here is my confusion, am I to use the Normal Binance Address or do I have to work on an extra Logic to create addresses on the smart contract etc.
Please I need guidance.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Do I understand correctly that you have some token in BSC network which you want to transfer to some other address? Do you own both the sender and the receiver addresses (have private keys for them)? You can edit your question to include the anwswers

Comment: I created a coin , now i want the coin to be transferrable between parties. So Mr A can send Money to Mr B, and Mr. B can send back to Mr A at some point. So i am asking, since the token is built on binance smart chain, do I have to leverage on BSC address to send the coin from one person to another

Comment: You can send the token to any address - even addesses to which nobody has access.

Comment: really? Do i need private keys to run that? I want to integrate it to my Node.Js backend. Do i need Private keys or just the address and all??

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to an address which owns some tokens (for example because you created the token contract), you can send the tokens to any address you wish. To send the tokens, you need to sign a transaction, and for that you need the private key.

One private key is used to sign transactions for one public address, so you'll need the private key for the address which owns the tokens. Whatever wallet you use probably handles most of this for you.

The receiver address can really be any valid address, even an address which is never used (and will possibly never be used).